# How to limit returned rows using max characters in sqlite query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-limit

Say I have `students` table with one column named `name` as follows:

```
| name |
--------
Jhon
Natalie Kocher
Jonell Dickson
Irvin
Kiara Audet
Shawna Duvall
Cobey Maryellen
Kenny
Lindsy Taylor
```

How to get all rows that under 6 characters so that I get the following name:

```
Jhon
Irvin
Kenny
```

In case that's not possible at least how to sort / set the order of returned rows start from smallest length of chars to the longest.

Thanks,

> About SQLite query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `length()` function:

```
select t.*
from t
where length(name) < 6;
```

Or you can use `not like`:

```
where name not like '______%'  -- there are 6 underscores
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try it and come back to hit that check icon if succeed